# How can I use Chef library modules in Non-Chef-related classes?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have an application which uses a combination of Chef, Vagrant, and custom Ruby code I've written to build a Virtual Machine.  The application does a lot of things aside from creating the virtual machine, so I've written a class `App` which lives outside of Chef, but which has methods which would also be useful as chef helper methods.

Is it possible to import a Chef Library module into my custom class so that I can share these methods accordingly?

When I tried to do this, I used the following approach:

Given the project directory which contains

```
--| cookbooks
  --| helpers
    --| libraries
          DemoStructureHelper.rb
--| lib
      main_app.rb
...

Vagrantfile
```

1. `main_app.rb` contains my custom class `App`
2. Vagrantfile references `App` as one would expect: `app = App.new` and so forth
3. The `DemoStuctureHelper.rb` has a module `DemoStructureHelper` with a collection of methods which would also benefit my App class

The DemoStructureHelper is defined like so:

```rb
module DemoStructureHelper
  def self.my_helper_method
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

In main_app.rb, I have:

```rb
require_relative '../cookbooks/helpers/libraries/demo_structure_helper'

include DemoStructureHelper
class App
  def my_custom_method
    DemoStructureHelper.my_helper_method
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

When I use the App class in the Vagrantfile, I get the following error using the above:

`Message: NameError: uninitialized constant App::DemoStructureHelper`

My thought was that I somehow needed to make my class aware of Chef; perhaps something like one of these:

```rb
include Chef::DemoStructureHelper
include Chef::DemoStructure::Helper
include Chef::Helper::DemoStructure
```

etc., but these all yield:

`Message: NameError: uninitialized constant App::Chef`

Hence my question: How can I include a Chef library module in my custom class outside of chef so that I can share methods between chef and my custom code?

Comment: i'm not sure what `import` does?  that might be vagrant and not ruby?  the usual ruby methods are `include`/`extend`/`prepend` for modules, but since you've got class methods hanging off of a module and you're invoking them as `MyModule.mymethod` you don't need any of those.

Comment: Thanks @lamont -- `import` was a typo and should've been `include`.

What I've found since originally writing this is that, since Vagrant is involved, the issue has more to do with making sure the relevant classes are available on the VM for the chef run to access.  At the moment I "solve" this by keeping versions of the classes (which often need to be extended anyway) inside of a helper cookbook library so that chef has access to them. The only downside thus far is that there's a bit of duplication -- some classes exist on both the guest and host. It's a low-impact duplication, though.